# ¿Como abrir nueva activity no con la posición sino con el nombre?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, activity

Lo que quiero es que para dirigirse a una nueva actividad se tenga en cuenta el nombre y no la posición, por ejemplo aqui tengo dos nombres "Ciclismo" y "Correr" y aquí el código:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lista;
    ArrayList<Datos> arraydatos = new ArrayList<Datos>();
    Datos datos;
    adapterdatos adapter = new adapterdatos(this, arraydatos);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_lista);


        datos = new Datos(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ciclistapng), "Ciclismo", "Imagen de tipo PNG");
        arraydatos.add(datos);
        datos = new Datos(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corredor), "Correr", "Imagen de tipo PNG");
        arraydatos.add(datos);


        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lista);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MainActivity.super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_context_menu, menu);
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent ci = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ciclismo.class);
                        startActivity(ci);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ciclismo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete_id:
                arraydatos.remove(info.position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.añadir_id:
                arraydatos.add(datos);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Añadido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return MainActivity.super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Quiero que en case no sea por numero sino por su nombre en el listview.
Gracias.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si lo implementas de la siguiente manera, que si en un futuro traduces la app, funcione igual

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente para abrir una `Activity` por su nombre, se realizaría de esta forma, usando el paquete de la aplicación el cual se puede obtener mediante el método `getPackageName()`:

```
  try {
         String packagename = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName(packagename +".nombreActivity"));
         startActivity(intent);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

o puedes definir directamente el `packagename`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName("com.mypackage.app.nombreActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Recuerda que en este caso la clase a abrir debe ser una `Activity` por lo tanto extender de `Activity`, `AppCompatActivity`, etc..

---

En tu caso como ejemplo sería:

```
  try {
         String packagename = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
         Intent ci = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName(packagename +".ciclismo"));
         startActivity(ci);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Para abrir nueva activity por el nombre, considero que debes tener en tu objeto un mètodo para obtenerlo, por ejemplo `.getNombre()`, en realidad necesitas la posiciòn ya que de esta forma obtienes el elemento respectivo al dar click en el listado.

```
     @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                  if(arraydatos.get(position).getNombre.equals("Ciclismo"){
                      //Abre Ciclismo.
                  }else if(arraydatos.get(position).getNombre.equals("Correr")){
                     //Abre Correr!.
                  }


                  /*switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent ci = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ciclismo.class);
                        startActivity(ci);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ciclismo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }*/
            }
```

Comment: ¿Me podrías dar el ejemplo con mi código por favor?

Comment: ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: Bueno, muchas gracias.

Comment: @E7T14A como abrir el Activity y como saber el nombre para abrir el Activity.

Comment: Esta bien pero como puedes ver tengo un menú contextual con la opción de eliminar un item, entonces al eliminar ese item ("Ciclismo") mediante esa opción el item siguiente ("Correr") me abre la activity de ciclismo, entonces que puedo hacer para que solo Ciclismo me dirija a su activity y si no esta entonces que Correr se dirija a la activity que le corresponde